# Error in Install Nodejs on Windows

Tags: windows-7, node.js

I want to [install node.js](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs) in my Windows 7 machine but having error.

Errors are :
1) when I am trying to configure it shows soome file is not found

```
Anand@TANISH-LAPTOP3 ~/node
$ ./configure
Checking for program g++ or c++          : c:\mingw\bin\g++.exe
Checking for program cpp                 : c:\mingw\bin\cpp.exe
Checking for program ar                  : c:\mingw\bin\ar.exe
Checking for program ranlib              : c:\mingw\bin\ranlib.exe
Checking for g++                         : ok
Checking for program gcc or cc           : c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
Checking for program ar                  : c:\mingw\bin\ar.exe
Checking for program ranlib              : c:\mingw\bin\ranlib.exe
Checking for gcc                         : ok
Checking for library dl                  : not found
Checking for openssl                     : not found
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : yes
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : yes
Checking for library util                : not found
Checking for library rt                  : not found
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : no
'configure' finished successfully (6.395s)
```

2) Then after when I am trying to make for build it shows this

```
/c/Program: Files: No such file or directory
scons: *** [obj\release\accessors.o] Error 127

Waf: Leaving directory `c:\Users\Anand\node\build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2):
        {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Can Anybody know what is this error about? How can I over come this error?

Comment: scons is a python based build tool that v8 uses, you need python 2.4+.  Though really, you're better off install node in a linux virtual box.

Comment: Thanx for quick reply, but i have installed python 2.7 in my windows 7 machine. And I am instructed to install in windows 7. So i can't think of Linux.

Comment: it looks like you might be running into a known bug: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-mingw, you can also try the binaries http://node-js.prcn.co.cc/.

Comment: Thanks generalhenry, but still having a problem of while make command executes

 /c/Program: Files: No such file or directory
scons: *** [obj\release\accessors.o] Error 127

Waf: Leaving directory `c:\Users\Anand\node\build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2):
        {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}
make: *** [program] Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try out node on windows, there's a brand [new node.exe binary since version 0.5.1](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.5.1/node.exe).

Still, the unix culture runs in node.js' ecosystem. So using a linux virtual box is not a bad idea.